# Как установить libressl на Manjaro?

Tags: linux, manjaro

Пытаюсь поставить libressl, но после компиляции во время установки выходит следующее:

```
ошибка: не удалось завершить транзакцию (конфликтующие файлы)
libressl: '/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' существует в файловой системе
libressl: '/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0' существует в файловой системе
```

Файлы принадлежат пакету openssl-1.0 1.0.2.l-1 не понимаю, что в этом случае надо делать, т.к. удалить openssl не получается слишком много программ зависит от него.

Comment: А как пытаетесь установить ? В репозиториях нет

Comment: Через AUR и makepkg

Comment: Можете попробывать с опцией `--force`

Comment: sudo pacman -U libressl/libressl-2.6.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz --force ?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте с АУРа: `yaourt -S --force имя_пакета`

Comment: Неа, выходит так, что не работает NetworkManager

Comment: значит нетворк менеджер не готов работать с либрессл. она вообще вам зачем? если для конкретных задач, то ld_preload из папочки

Answer (score 0):

Практически во всех дистрах Linux, на данный момент, все пакеты "завязаны" на openssl. Поэтому просто так собрать и установить параллельно/вместо openssl libressl - у вас не получится!
Вам нужно или пересобирать все пакеты, которые используют openssl, на поддержку libressl, либо собирать некоторые, которые вы хотите перевести на работу с libressl.

Пример из моей жизни, у меня дефолтный пакет openssl в дистре сейчас - 1.0.2l-2.2, но мне для nginx нужен openssl 1.1, поэтому я при сборке nginx, качаю исходники 1.1, и собираю его именно с этой версией, явно указывая при конфигурации в .spec:

```
...
%define openssl_version 1.1.0f
...
--with-openssl=~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/openssl-1.1.0f  \
...
```

и после сборки имею:

```
nginx/1.13.6                                                                                                                           
built by gcc 7.2.1 20170927 [gcc-7-branch revision 253227] (SUSE Linux)                                                                               
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```